# How to dynamically load data inside page in nodejs project?

Tags: node.js

How can I dynamically load data inside a page using nodejs?

In my case, I actually fetch some information from other sites and load it using ejs and render it. Due to the slowness of other sites from where I fetch, it takes time like around 3-5 seconds. So it simply means if users want to visit it, they have to wait 5 seconds before information can be presented to them.

I want to fix this problem by dynamically loading content inside a page means if the user visits the page, it will load the page immediately with all static content and it will say "loading" inside the area where fetched information will be shown.

How can I achieve this? is there some sort of technology for nodejs to achieve this?
If yes, can you please provide me documentation link of it?

Comment: You might want to checkout [NextJS](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching)

Comment: display 'loading' where you content is supposed to go and add a script to the site which gets your content and then simply replaces the 'loading' with the content

Comment: Something like that: `fetch(url).then((res)=>res.json()).then(data=>document.getElementById('loading').innerHTML = data)`